# Gitlab pipeline always passed although my python script failed

Tags: python, gitlab

I have gitlab CI pipeline, it always passed although my python script failed.

I have a URI that calls different apis and fetches data. It uses many URI some uri is not working, and it got failed to fetch data, but still it is making passed to the CI pipeline whether it should expect to fail.

How can I make ci pipeline failed if my pyscript failed.

I have below code

```
 def connect(url,port):
    ##code that connecting url 
 end

 error =[]

 with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=25) as executor:
 # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
     future_to_conn = {executor.submit(connect, host, 22): host for host in arr}
     for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_conn):
         url = future_to_conn[future]
         try:
             data = future.result()
         except Exception as exc:
             print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
             errors.append('generated an exception: '+ exec)                 
         else:
             print("Completed")


if(len(errors) > 0):
      sys.exit("Execptin occured ", str(errors))
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("Execution completed")
```

I have below simple Dockerfile
FROM pyth3...
USER root
WORKDIR ./

```
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "./app.py"]
```

and

script.sh

```
echo "starting build--------------"
docker build -f Dockerfile -t python .
echo "Build Completed-------------"
docker run --rm -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -v "$PWD":/mnt python './app.py'
```

gitlab simple file

```
Run Python:
  stage: deploy
  script:  (./script.sh Git=True Cron=False Detail=NA)
  allow_failure: true
```

although I am using sys.exit("...") still not failing the pipeline it is always showing passed

Comment: Could it have something to do with `allow_failure: true`?

Comment: Thanks smac89 for your comment..what I have to do with it make it false and try it?

Comment: That's exactly what you should do. Also no need to wrap your script in brackets. That will actually create a subshell, which may lead to further issues

Comment: ok I am trying it if success please make your comments as a post will accept it

Comment: Execptin occured ['generated an exception: <built-in function exec>']
Run Successfully.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded

Comment: still pass I made allow_failure :false

Comment: Is that script python? What is `end`? Also `sys.exit` only takes one parameter, but you've given it two. Fix the syntax of your script please. You can also try to add the following to the top of your `script.sh`: `#!/bin/bash -e`. The `-e` means that the script will exit with the same exit status as the first command that fails. Finally, there is no need to supply `python './app.py'` to the docker run command; Just `docker run --rm -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -v "$PWD":/mnt` is fine

Comment: smac thanks again for your reply ......I used ```sys.exit(1)``` but still no hope .......I need to pass the paramter in docker run like ```python ./app.py "$user" "$clientid"``` like this as we need the variables to runt he python file

Comment: seconding @smac89 - use `#!/bin/bash -e` at the top of your bash script or add `set -e` within the script - otherwise the script will ignore errors

Comment: adding `#!/bin/bash -e` works! Thx!